# Save Retrofit2 API call to cache with RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I am new to rxJava and Retrofit2, but I cannot seem to figure out how to achieve the desired situation:

1. Get list of Places (Retrofit2 API interface) This will give a JSON Array with place objects
2. Put JSON array in HashMap  (Where to handle this?)
3. Put HashMap in a Singleton so it's cached and can be called throughout the app with a getInstance

The JSON array contains hundreds of 'places' that I wish to cache (Singleton) so I do not have to make calls for each change within the app.

Interface (myAPI)

```
    /**
     * RxJava testing endpoint
     * @return Observable list of Places
     * count = 0 means everything
     */
    @GET("place/search?count=0")
    rx.Observable<List<Place>> loadPlacesRx();
```

Singleton

```
...
private static PlaceSingleton ourInstance = new PlaceSingleton();
    private static RxJavaCallAdapterFactory rxAdapter =
            RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io());

    private static Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(rxAdapter)
            .baseUrl(myAPI.BASE_URL)
            .build();

    // Prepare call in Retrofit2
    private static MyAPI myAPI = retrofit.create(MyAPI.class);

    /**
     * This method should handle the steps mentioned above
     */
    public void getAllPlaces() {

    poiList = myAPI.loadPlacesRx()
    .map(Place -> ...
...
```

Comment: In `map` function add each place to your `PlaceSingleton`, that contains the hash map. Instead of `map` operator, you can use `doOnNext`

Answer (score 0):

You can save into your own cache serializating object into a string, using Gson and save it to shared preferences.

Using Gson:
To serializate:

```
new Gson().toJson(yourObject);
```

And to deserializate:

```
new Gson().fromJson(stringObject);
```

Using Jakson:

To serializate:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String objectString = mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
```

To deserializate:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Object object = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, Object.class);
```

Comment: How to handle the observable list and what about the hashmap then?

Comment: Why do you want to put a list into a hashmap? This is unclear for me. You can just serializate the list and nothing else. Hashmap is just like an array, but with key.

Comment: The objects have an id, isn't it faster to search within a hashmap<placeid, placeObject> than an array?

Comment: So you want to search for a place with a place id? In this case you can use a hashmap but you can create own search in array with binary search. That is more memory eficient. But hashmap has O(1) for search in best case, O(n) in worst case. You can map that list into a hashmap using `map` function from rx, given an array and return a HashMap, then iterate through list and add objects to a new hashmap instance that will be returned. You decide.

Comment: What about using the map function and making a hashmap singleton that I call in the splashscreen once, so I do a call for all places once and then within the app I use the singleton hashmap

Comment: You can save it to application level or cache it, as my above answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126700/discussion-between-s-r-lobato-and-florescu-george-ctlin).